# using emoji python library with pyrogram

Tags: python, emoji, pyrogram

i am making a script for telegram using pyrogram, the problem comes when i try to use the emoji library. What I need is to demojize the texts that I receive from a bot to later process them, but using the function `emoji.demojize("text")` keeps throwing me the error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: unexpected end of data`. This does not happen to me when I implement the emoji library in a bot using telebot, so I imagine the problem may be with pyrogram and how it solves the messages, I don't really know. please if anyone knows what it could be it would be very useful. In case u need it, the code goes something like this:

```
from pyrogram import Client, filters, idle
import emoji

app1 = Cliente('MyAccount', api_id, api_hash)

@app1.on_message(filters.chat("@somebot") & filters.incoming)
def listener(client, message):
    print(emoji.demojize(message.text))

app1.start()
idle()
```

Answer (score 1):

try this , I had same problem and solve by this.

```
print(emoji.demojize(message.text.encode('utf-16').decode("utf-16")))
```